# How to fix a cabinet toe board which has been damaged?

Tags: kitchens, woodworking, dishwasher

Just moved in here and it looks like the plinth has been hacked away at to allow the dishwasher to open.

I don't have access to any power tools, nor hugely interested in buying any as this is a small flat, I don't have a place to store these things.

How can I fix this to make it look reasonable? I'm not opposed to buying files to file it down or something.

[image: Plinth]

Comment: Thick white tape run just above the ragged edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file is going to take forever.  I dont think that a powered jigsaw will fit there.

There are multitools like this which are cheap enough to buy.  It would require a steady hand.

[image]

The best bet I think is hacksaw or a coping saw.  And then file it down.  Or use crip659's advice and to use a trim of some sort to make the hole look level.

Comment: Instead of depending on a steady hand, find/make a scrap of wood the right height and use that as a guide.

Answer (score 9):

Dishwashers do not have cabinet toe kick trim in front of them.  They carry their own trim. Having the toe kick run across prevents removal for service, unless the entire toe kick strip is removed.

Cut the toe kick just a mm or 1/16" beyond the edges of the cabinets, in the area of the blue lines as shown.  Use an oscillating tool (as
Rohit Gupta suggested).

[image]

There may be trim behind the gray toe kick. If not you may need to find a new [lower trim panel](https://www.partswarehouse.com/Bosch-Panel-Base-BSH-00745002-p/BSH-00745002.htm?Click=365719&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA44OtBhAOEiwAj4gpOaCKChINz7Rwb41d-sI7VpGMFZREgP8JmqPjkWgHf_R7WEq6RHZ3lhoC36MQAvD_BwE) for your model of dishwasher.

Comment: This is the best solution, IMO, but I wonder if this model is actually designed as a full built-in.

Comment: I think this is supposed to be here, our neighbors have the same thing, though it looks like their one has enough room for the door to open, what I imagined happened here is that someone cut into it to allow the door to open properly

Comment: Your neighbors may have had the same lazy cabinet installers. It is not uncommon in track housing.

Comment: If some dishwashers cannot have toe kick in front of some doesn't mean ALL dishwashers shouldn't have them. Mine has one, without a cut and have no issues with that.

Comment: In over 50 years of remodeling homes I have not come across a dishwasher that is installed allowing the cabinets toe kick to be extended across the front of the appliance. CAN it be done?  Yes , obviously.  Should it be done?  NO, for obvious reasons.  If there is such an animal as a dishwasher that can be installed and recommends the cabinet toe kick be installed across the front, please be kind enough to provide a link, or at least a product name and model so I and others may be able to educate ourselves.